# Why does a String[] takes a lot more space than a char[]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, memory, char

### Objective:

I was writing a `Java` application to read large text files, where data is represented in the format of character columns.. E.g.:

```
A B R S Y E ...
R E W I W I ...
E Q B U O Y ...
W Q V G O R ...
```

i.e. single alphabet separated by a space. **Each such row has millions of such characters.** And each file has several such lines.

### Setup:

My job was to manipulate the file by columns. So I read the file line-by-line, split on `' '` and created array. From such arrays, I created a 2-D array. Everything was fine as I tested it on a small file, with 10 rows. But it started failing when I read files with say 500 rows. My machine and `JVM` have lots of memory, so I didn't expect this. Hence I did some profiling and saw that  reading the lines into `String[]` was taking a LOT more memory than expected. Hence I changed `String[]` to `char[]`. Memory usage came down dramatically and everything was fine.

### Question:

My question is why does `String[]` takes so much more space than `char[]`? Is it because it is like an array of Objects? (since String is also an Object). If someone can explain the low-level details, that would be really great.

### EDIT 1:

Here is what I was doing before:

```
String[] parts = line.split(" ");                // Creating a String[]
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
String rowNoSpaces = line.replaceAll(" ", "");   // Removing all the spaces
char[] columns= rowNoSpaces.toCharArray();       // Creating a char[], instead of String[]
```

Let me know if more info needed.

Comment: Also, this might depend on the Java version used. For an example see http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/.

Comment: How are you building your strings?

Comment: Downvoter, care to leave a comment?

Comment: Post some code, it's quite possible you're doing something else which is inefficient.

Comment: @SLaks: I am just splitting the line on ' '. Not building any other string.

Comment: Show us your code; there are lots of unanswered questions here.

Comment: Did you change `string` to `char[]`, `string[]` to `char[][]` or really what you wrote there?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Added more info in the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `char` is a primitive type, an array of chars will store those bytes directly in the array with no per-character overhead at all.

By contrast, `String` is an object, so the array will store pointers to `String` instances elsewhere in the heap, each of which has its own overhead of vtable, length, & other information (including a separate reference to a `char[]` with the actual text).  Having lots of objects also increases the risk of GC heap fragmentation.

In addition, if you build the strings by concatenation instead of `StringBuilder`s, you'll also get lots of extra copies taking up much more memory.

Comment: You know arrays in Java are first-class objects, just like a string?

Comment: @Deduplicator: My understanding is that he has 1 `char[]` versus lots of `String`s.

Comment: @SLaks My understanding was that each line was a `String[]`, which each index in the string being a one-character String object.

Comment: @mbomb007: Ouch; that would be much worse.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. +1. Is there a way to calculate exact overhead of String v/s char? Just curious.